# PHP: getting result from XML collection

Tags: php, loops, xml

I'm trying to read an XML file with PHP but I'm not able to get data and can't figure out why.

XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FavoriteListResponse>
   <metadata>
      <offset>0</offset>
      <limit>20</limit>
      <total>1</total>
   </metadata>
   <favorites>
      <favorites objectType="Product">
         <id>5831fd52f9f0c0a80c88dafa</id>
         <productId>511290702</productId>
         <imageId>39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04</imageId>
         <product>
            <id>511290702</id>
            <name>Misha Black Cropped Leather Jacket With Asymmetrical Front Zipper</name>
            <brandedName>Mackage Misha Black Cropped Leather Jacket With Asymmetrical Front Zipper</brandedName>
            <unbrandedName>Misha Black Cropped Leather Jacket With Asymmetrical Front Zipper</unbrandedName>
            <currency>USD</currency>
            <price>620.0</price>
            <priceLabel>Sold Out</priceLabel>
            <inStock>false</inStock>
            <stock>
               <stock>
                  <size>
                     <name>M</name>
                  </size>
               </stock>
               <stock>
                  <size>
                     <name>XXS</name>
                  </size>
               </stock>
            </stock>
            <retailer>
               <id>596</id>
               <name>Mackage</name>
               <score>242</score>
            </retailer>
            <brand>
               <id>1590</id>
               <name>Mackage</name>
            </brand>
            <locale>en_US</locale>
            <description>Misha by Mackage is a washed leather jacket for women crafted from genuine lambskin. Fitted silhouette cropped above the hips. Asymmetrical full-length zip closure. Dual zippered front pockets. Nickel hardware. Available in black and sand. Fits true to size. Fitted silhouette. Washed genuine lambskin leather jacket. Cropped above the hips. Padded shoulder yoke. Hem yoke with stitching at the back bottom. Asymmetrical full-length two-way zip closure. Nickel hardware. Coat length from shoulder to hem : 17inches / 43.2cm Model is 5'11/180 cm and wearing a size XS. Shell: 100% Lambskin. Lining (Woven): 100% Polyester.</description>
            <clickUrl>https://api.shopstyle.com/action/apiVisitRetailer?id=511290702&amp;pid=uid5044-35323862-95</clickUrl>
            <image>
               <sizes>
                  <Small>
                     <sizeName>Small</sizeName>
                     <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_small.jpg</url>
                     <width>32</width>
                     <height>40</height>
                     <actualWidth>11</actualWidth>
                     <actualHeight>40</actualHeight>
                  </Small>
                  <XLarge>
                     <sizeName>XLarge</sizeName>
                     <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_xlarge.jpg</url>
                     <width>328</width>
                     <height>410</height>
                     <actualWidth>111</actualWidth>
                     <actualHeight>410</actualHeight>
                  </XLarge>
                  <Medium>
                     <sizeName>Medium</sizeName>
                     <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_medium/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                     <width>112</width>
                     <height>140</height>
                     <actualWidth>38</actualWidth>
                     <actualHeight>140</actualHeight>
                  </Medium>
                  <Large>
                     <sizeName>Large</sizeName>
                     <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                     <width>164</width>
                     <height>205</height>
                     <actualWidth>55</actualWidth>
                     <actualHeight>205</actualHeight>
                  </Large>
                  <IPhoneSmall>
                     <sizeName>IPhoneSmall</sizeName>
                     <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_small.jpg</url>
                     <width>100</width>
                     <height>125</height>
                     <actualWidth>34</actualWidth>
                     <actualHeight>125</actualHeight>
                  </IPhoneSmall>
                  <Best>
                     <sizeName>Best</sizeName>
                     <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_best.jpg</url>
                     <width>720</width>
                     <height>900</height>
                     <actualWidth>243</actualWidth>
                     <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                  </Best>
                  <Original>
                     <sizeName>Original</sizeName>
                     <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_best.jpg</url>
                     <actualWidth>243</actualWidth>
                     <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                  </Original>
                  <IPhone>
                     <sizeName>IPhone</sizeName>
                     <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04.jpg</url>
                     <width>288</width>
                     <height>360</height>
                     <actualWidth>97</actualWidth>
                     <actualHeight>360</actualHeight>
                  </IPhone>
               </sizes>
               <id>39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04</id>
            </image>
            <alternateImages>
               <alternateImages>
                  <sizes>
                     <Small>
                        <sizeName>Small</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>32</width>
                        <height>40</height>
                        <actualWidth>11</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>40</actualHeight>
                     </Small>
                     <XLarge>
                        <sizeName>XLarge</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_xlarge.jpg</url>
                        <width>328</width>
                        <height>410</height>
                        <actualWidth>111</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>410</actualHeight>
                     </XLarge>
                     <Medium>
                        <sizeName>Medium</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_medium/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>112</width>
                        <height>140</height>
                        <actualWidth>38</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>140</actualHeight>
                     </Medium>
                     <Large>
                        <sizeName>Large</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>164</width>
                        <height>205</height>
                        <actualWidth>55</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>205</actualHeight>
                     </Large>
                     <IPhoneSmall>
                        <sizeName>IPhoneSmall</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>100</width>
                        <height>125</height>
                        <actualWidth>34</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>125</actualHeight>
                     </IPhoneSmall>
                     <Best>
                        <sizeName>Best</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_best.jpg</url>
                        <width>720</width>
                        <height>900</height>
                        <actualWidth>243</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                     </Best>
                     <Original>
                        <sizeName>Original</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04_best.jpg</url>
                        <actualWidth>243</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                     </Original>
                     <IPhone>
                        <sizeName>IPhone</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/39/d5/39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04.jpg</url>
                        <width>288</width>
                        <height>360</height>
                        <actualWidth>97</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>360</actualHeight>
                     </IPhone>
                  </sizes>
                  <id>39d5e666255e351aa42fca3a9b939d04</id>
               </alternateImages>
               <alternateImages>
                  <sizes>
                     <Small>
                        <sizeName>Small</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/56/c4/56c4c2a990fb868e7a27a57381330244_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>32</width>
                        <height>40</height>
                        <actualWidth>12</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>40</actualHeight>
                     </Small>
                     <XLarge>
                        <sizeName>XLarge</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/56/c4/56c4c2a990fb868e7a27a57381330244_xlarge.jpg</url>
                        <width>328</width>
                        <height>410</height>
                        <actualWidth>124</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>410</actualHeight>
                     </XLarge>
                     <Medium>
                        <sizeName>Medium</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/56/c4/56c4c2a990fb868e7a27a57381330244_medium/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>112</width>
                        <height>140</height>
                        <actualWidth>42</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>140</actualHeight>
                     </Medium>
                     <Large>
                        <sizeName>Large</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/56/c4/56c4c2a990fb868e7a27a57381330244/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>164</width>
                        <height>205</height>
                        <actualWidth>62</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>205</actualHeight>
                     </Large>
                     <IPhoneSmall>
                        <sizeName>IPhoneSmall</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/56/c4/56c4c2a990fb868e7a27a57381330244_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>100</width>
                        <height>125</height>
                        <actualWidth>38</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>125</actualHeight>
                     </IPhoneSmall>
                     <Best>
                        <sizeName>Best</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/56/c4/56c4c2a990fb868e7a27a57381330244_best.jpg</url>
                        <width>720</width>
                        <height>900</height>
                        <actualWidth>273</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                     </Best>
                     <Original>
                        <sizeName>Original</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/56/c4/56c4c2a990fb868e7a27a57381330244_best.jpg</url>
                        <actualWidth>273</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                     </Original>
                     <IPhone>
                        <sizeName>IPhone</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/56/c4/56c4c2a990fb868e7a27a57381330244.jpg</url>
                        <width>288</width>
                        <height>360</height>
                        <actualWidth>109</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>360</actualHeight>
                     </IPhone>
                  </sizes>
                  <id>56c4c2a990fb868e7a27a57381330244</id>
               </alternateImages>
               <alternateImages>
                  <sizes>
                     <Small>
                        <sizeName>Small</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/a9/b2/a9b2551df3fe88d30f596ab83a1e764c_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>32</width>
                        <height>40</height>
                        <actualWidth>10</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>40</actualHeight>
                     </Small>
                     <XLarge>
                        <sizeName>XLarge</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/a9/b2/a9b2551df3fe88d30f596ab83a1e764c_xlarge.jpg</url>
                        <width>328</width>
                        <height>410</height>
                        <actualWidth>108</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>410</actualHeight>
                     </XLarge>
                     <Medium>
                        <sizeName>Medium</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/a9/b2/a9b2551df3fe88d30f596ab83a1e764c_medium/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>112</width>
                        <height>140</height>
                        <actualWidth>37</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>140</actualHeight>
                     </Medium>
                     <Large>
                        <sizeName>Large</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/a9/b2/a9b2551df3fe88d30f596ab83a1e764c/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>164</width>
                        <height>205</height>
                        <actualWidth>54</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>205</actualHeight>
                     </Large>
                     <IPhoneSmall>
                        <sizeName>IPhoneSmall</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/a9/b2/a9b2551df3fe88d30f596ab83a1e764c_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>100</width>
                        <height>125</height>
                        <actualWidth>33</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>125</actualHeight>
                     </IPhoneSmall>
                     <Best>
                        <sizeName>Best</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/a9/b2/a9b2551df3fe88d30f596ab83a1e764c_best.jpg</url>
                        <width>720</width>
                        <height>900</height>
                        <actualWidth>236</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                     </Best>
                     <Original>
                        <sizeName>Original</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/a9/b2/a9b2551df3fe88d30f596ab83a1e764c_best.jpg</url>
                        <actualWidth>236</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                     </Original>
                     <IPhone>
                        <sizeName>IPhone</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/a9/b2/a9b2551df3fe88d30f596ab83a1e764c.jpg</url>
                        <width>288</width>
                        <height>360</height>
                        <actualWidth>94</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>360</actualHeight>
                     </IPhone>
                  </sizes>
                  <id>a9b2551df3fe88d30f596ab83a1e764c</id>
               </alternateImages>
               <alternateImages>
                  <sizes>
                     <Small>
                        <sizeName>Small</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/b8/2a/b82a3ff82915a288cedb59386eb74c4c_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>32</width>
                        <height>40</height>
                        <actualWidth>11</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>40</actualHeight>
                     </Small>
                     <XLarge>
                        <sizeName>XLarge</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/b8/2a/b82a3ff82915a288cedb59386eb74c4c_xlarge.jpg</url>
                        <width>328</width>
                        <height>410</height>
                        <actualWidth>114</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>410</actualHeight>
                     </XLarge>
                     <Medium>
                        <sizeName>Medium</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/b8/2a/b82a3ff82915a288cedb59386eb74c4c_medium/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>112</width>
                        <height>140</height>
                        <actualWidth>39</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>140</actualHeight>
                     </Medium>
                     <Large>
                        <sizeName>Large</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/b8/2a/b82a3ff82915a288cedb59386eb74c4c/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>164</width>
                        <height>205</height>
                        <actualWidth>57</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>205</actualHeight>
                     </Large>
                     <IPhoneSmall>
                        <sizeName>IPhoneSmall</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/b8/2a/b82a3ff82915a288cedb59386eb74c4c_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>100</width>
                        <height>125</height>
                        <actualWidth>35</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>125</actualHeight>
                     </IPhoneSmall>
                     <Best>
                        <sizeName>Best</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/b8/2a/b82a3ff82915a288cedb59386eb74c4c_best.jpg</url>
                        <width>720</width>
                        <height>900</height>
                        <actualWidth>250</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                     </Best>
                     <Original>
                        <sizeName>Original</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/b8/2a/b82a3ff82915a288cedb59386eb74c4c_best.jpg</url>
                        <actualWidth>250</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                     </Original>
                     <IPhone>
                        <sizeName>IPhone</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/b8/2a/b82a3ff82915a288cedb59386eb74c4c.jpg</url>
                        <width>288</width>
                        <height>360</height>
                        <actualWidth>100</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>360</actualHeight>
                     </IPhone>
                  </sizes>
                  <id>b82a3ff82915a288cedb59386eb74c4c</id>
               </alternateImages>
               <alternateImages>
                  <sizes>
                     <Small>
                        <sizeName>Small</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/e4/9d/e49db198c964ac5c339b2924687c633c_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>32</width>
                        <height>40</height>
                        <actualWidth>32</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>40</actualHeight>
                     </Small>
                     <XLarge>
                        <sizeName>XLarge</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/e4/9d/e49db198c964ac5c339b2924687c633c_xlarge.jpg</url>
                        <width>328</width>
                        <height>410</height>
                        <actualWidth>328</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>410</actualHeight>
                     </XLarge>
                     <Medium>
                        <sizeName>Medium</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/e4/9d/e49db198c964ac5c339b2924687c633c_medium/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>112</width>
                        <height>140</height>
                        <actualWidth>112</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>140</actualHeight>
                     </Medium>
                     <Large>
                        <sizeName>Large</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/sim/e4/9d/e49db198c964ac5c339b2924687c633c/mackage-misha-black-cropped-leather-jacket-with-asymmetrical-front-zipper.jpg</url>
                        <width>164</width>
                        <height>205</height>
                        <actualWidth>164</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>205</actualHeight>
                     </Large>
                     <IPhoneSmall>
                        <sizeName>IPhoneSmall</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/e4/9d/e49db198c964ac5c339b2924687c633c_small.jpg</url>
                        <width>100</width>
                        <height>125</height>
                        <actualWidth>100</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>125</actualHeight>
                     </IPhoneSmall>
                     <Best>
                        <sizeName>Best</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/e4/9d/e49db198c964ac5c339b2924687c633c_best.jpg</url>
                        <width>720</width>
                        <height>900</height>
                        <actualWidth>720</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>900</actualHeight>
                     </Best>
                     <Original>
                        <sizeName>Original</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/pim/e4/9d/e49db198c964ac5c339b2924687c633c_best.jpg</url>
                     </Original>
                     <IPhone>
                        <sizeName>IPhone</sizeName>
                        <url>https://img.shopstyle-cdn.com/mim/e4/9d/e49db198c964ac5c339b2924687c633c.jpg</url>
                        <width>288</width>
                        <height>360</height>
                        <actualWidth>288</actualWidth>
                        <actualHeight>360</actualHeight>
                     </IPhone>
                  </sizes>
                  <id>e49db198c964ac5c339b2924687c633c</id>
               </alternateImages>
            </alternateImages>
            <extractDate>2016-02-16</extractDate>
            <lastModified>2017-02-05</lastModified>
            <seeMoreLabel>Mackage Leather Jackets</seeMoreLabel>
            <preOwned>false</preOwned>
            <rental>false</rental>
            <colors />
            <sizes>
               <size>
                  <name>XXS</name>
                  <canonicalSize>
                     <id>79</id>
                     <name>XXS (0)</name>
                  </canonicalSize>
               </size>
               <size>
                  <name>M</name>
                  <canonicalSize>
                     <id>85</id>
                     <name>M (8-10)</name>
                  </canonicalSize>
               </size>
            </sizes>
            <categories>
               <category>
                  <id>leather-jackets</id>
                  <name>Leather Jackets</name>
                  <shortName>Leather</shortName>
                  <fullName>Women's Leather Jackets</fullName>
                  <localizedId>leather-jackets</localizedId>
               </category>
            </categories>
            <badges />
         </product>
         <date>
            <date>2016-11-20</date>
            <timestamp>1479671122</timestamp>
            <friendly>Nov 20, 2016</friendly>
         </date>
         <objectId>511290702</objectId>
      </favorites>
   </favorites>
</FavoriteListResponse>
```

I can't figure it out. Hope someone is willing to help :)

Comment: You can use `simplexml_load_string` if that **XML** is in a string variable, if it'a a file use `simplexml_load_file` you can refere to the manual on how to use both : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML is any easy way to go for this data.  This code assumes that the data is in a file, but just change the `simplexml_load_file` to `simplexml_load_string` and pass the XML in there.

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );


$xml = simplexml_load_file('t1.xml');
foreach( $xml->favorites->favorites->product as $product ){
    echo "Product name=".(string)$product->name.PHP_EOL;
    echo "Retailer=".(string)$product->retailer->name.PHP_EOL;
    foreach ( $product->sizes->size as $size )    {
        echo "Size:".(string)$size->name.PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo "Small image=".(string)$product->image->sizes->Small->url;
}
```

This only shows part of the data, but I hope it gives the idea of how to use the structure of XML. Using `$xml->favorites` gives you the favorites element in the $xml value.  So `$xml->favorites->favorites->product` will go through each product, and then `$product->name` gives you the name element.  From each product, this code uses `$product->sizes->size` to go through each size, but the same could be done for any of the data items.

This outputs (with your example XML ):

```
Product name=Misha Black Cropped Leather Jacket With Asymmetrical Front Zipper
Retailer=Mackage
Size:XXS
Size:M
```

Comment: can you please help me out from that.?and how can i get image of that really i am just getting frustrating.first time i am doing that so please help me in that @Nigel Ren

Comment: There is only 1 product in the example XML you attached.  I have also added an extra line which extracts one of the image URL's. Should be able to alter this for different images.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this for my work purpose, you can make a try using this,

```
/**
 * Class xml2array
 */
class xml2array {

    var $arrOutput = array();
    var $resParser;
    var $strXmlData;

    function parse($strInputXML) {

        $this->resParser = xml_parser_create ();
        xml_set_object($this->resParser,$this);
        xml_set_element_handler($this->resParser, "tagOpen", "tagClosed");

        xml_set_character_data_handler($this->resParser, "tagData");

        $this->strXmlData = xml_parse($this->resParser,$strInputXML );
        if(!$this->strXmlData) {
            die(sprintf("XML error: %s at line %d",
                xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($this->resParser)),
                xml_get_current_line_number($this->resParser)));
        }

        xml_parser_free($this->resParser);

        return $this->arrOutput;
    }
    function tagOpen($parser, $name, $attrs) {
        $tag=array("name"=>$name,"attrs"=>$attrs);
        array_push($this->arrOutput,$tag);
    }

    function tagData($parser, $tagData) {
        if(trim($tagData)) {
            if(isset($this->arrOutput[count($this->arrOutput)-1]['tagData'])) {
                $this->arrOutput[count($this->arrOutput)-1]['tagData'] .= $tagData;
            }
            else {
                $this->arrOutput[count($this->arrOutput)-1]['tagData'] = $tagData;
            }
        }
    }

    function tagClosed($parser, $name) {
        $this->arrOutput[count($this->arrOutput)-2]['children'][] = $this->arrOutput[count($this->arrOutput)-1];
        array_pop($this->arrOutput);
    }
}


$xml_file = file_get_contents('yourxmlfilename.xml');
$objXML = new xml2array();
$arrOutput = $objXML->parse($xml_file);

print '<pre>';
print_r($arrOutput); //print it out, or do whatever!
print '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function actionFindDataByXMLTag( $result, $xml_tag, $xml_end_tag, $count = null ) {

    $next_string = '';

    $result_array = array();
    $stop = 500;//only 500 items values will be selected

    $i = 0;
    while($i < $stop) {

        if($next_string == '') {

            $from = $result;
        } else {
            $from = $next_string;
        }

        $position = strpos($from, $xml_tag) + strlen($xml_tag);
        $start = substr($from, $position);
        $end = strpos($start, $xml_end_tag);

        $terr_result = substr($start, 0, $end);

        if($terr_result == '') {
            break;
        } else {
            array_push($result_array, $terr_result);
        }

        $next_string = substr($start, $end + strlen($xml_end_tag));

        //var_dump( $next_string );

        $i++;
    }

    return $result_array;
}
```